# python正規表現　文字列内の数字範囲制限

Tags: python, python3, 正規表現

reモジュールによる正規表現で、001-899までの数字の文字列を許可したいのですが、記述方法が分かりません。

```py
import re

pat = re.compile('000:[0-8]/d{2}')

txt = input()

print(pat.fullmatch(txt))
```

このコードでは、000-899までの表現にマッチします。
これに000だけ否定するようにすればよいのかと思いますが、表記方法が思いつきません。

Comment: タイトルは単語を並べるだけではなく、質問内容が伝わるものを心がけてください。 / この内容であれば単純に数値として大小を比較する…ではだめなのでしょうか？

Comment: 制御構文の一部を抜き出しているので、本投稿内容では数値比較のほうが良いようになると思いますが、ほかに判断すべきパターン部分があるためです。

Comment: 「001-899までの数字の文字列を許可したい」「このコードでは、000-899までの表現にマッチ」という質問なので 3桁分の正規表現と誤解していました。
`000:001` から `000:899` までなら, 質問はそのように記述してください(紛らわしいので)。(`000`否定の意味での 正規表現`000:`かと判断していました。`\\`を`/`と記述しているように)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> これに000だけ否定するようにすればよいのかと思いますが、

```py
import re

pat = re.compile('000:(?!000)[0-8]\d{2}')
txt = input()
print(pat.fullmatch(txt))
```

```bash
$ python3 match_num.py
000:000
None

$ python3 match_num.py
000:001
<re.Match object; span=(0, 7), match='000:001'>

$ python3 match_num.py
000:899
<re.Match object; span=(0, 7), match='000:899'>

$ python3 match_num.py
000:900
None

$ python3 match_num.py
000:000000
None

$ python3 match_num.py
000:0001
None

$ python3 match_num.py
000:1234
None
```

Answer (score 0):

不完全だけど以下のように記述できます
(`match`使ってるので 4文字テキストでもヒットする可能性がある)

でも, コメントにもあるように数値としての大小比較が望ましいような

```py
>>> [n for n in range(1000) if not re.match(r'(?=[0-8]\d{2})(?!000)', format(n, '03d'))]

[0, 900, 901, 902, 903, 904, 905, 906, 907, 908, 909, 910, 911, 912, 913,
914, 915, 916, 917, 918, 919, 920, 921, 922, 923, 924, 925, 926, 927, 928,
929, 930, 931, 932, 933, 934, 935, 936, 937, 938, 939, 940, 941, 942, 943,
944, 945, 946, 947, 948, 949, 950, 951, 952, 953, 954, 955, 956, 957, 958,
959, 960, 961, 962, 963, 964, 965, 966, 967, 968, 969, 970, 971, 972, 973,
974, 975, 976, 977, 978, 979, 980, 981, 982, 983, 984, 985, 986, 987, 988,
989, 990, 991, 992, 993, 994, 995, 996, 997, 998, 999]
```